# Glassfish cannot connect to remote MySQL but localhost can

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, glassfish

please give me a chance to explain my mysterious situation.

My Glassfish server cannot connect to the remote MySQL database.

I checked following instructions

1. ping to remote host - OK
2. connect via mysql command (mysql -h *remote* -u *user* -p) - OK
3. ssh port forwarding (ssh -L13306:localhost:3306 *remote*) and configure the glassfish to use it (jdbc://127.0.0.0:13306/mydb) - OK

I think my configurations (server name, database name, user name and password) are correct.
But still cannot connect to the database.

### My environment:

#### local side

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Oracle Java 1.8.0 u131
- Glassfish 4.1 (build 13)
- MySQL Connector/J 5.1.41

#### remote side

- FreeBSD 11
- MySQL 5.5.46

I have googled last night, but cannot found the answer.

**28 Apr. Edited:**

My server.log says:

```
[2017-04-26T09:03:07.932+0900] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [test.connection.pool.failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=admin-listen
er(6)] [timeMillis: 1493164987932] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ MysqlMacms ], Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.]]

[2017-04-26T09:03:07.940+0900] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1493164987940] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=admtkMysqlMacms}']]
```

Comment: I have tested with Payara Server 4.1.1.171.1 #badassfish (build 139), but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: I wonder some Java policy and/or apparmor blocks outgoing packets.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281683/jdbc-connection-to-remote-mysql-fails?rq=1 seems same problem.

Comment: can you please post the error you get with a complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

The first reason for the connection failure might is your jdbc url. You show

```
jdbc://127.0.0.0:13306/mydb
```

Although 172.0.0.0 is a valid loopback address (all 127.0.0.0/8 are) localhost normally is configured to be 127.0.0.**1**. You are missing as well the *mysql* specification:

So change that to

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:13306/mydb
```

The second possible reason for the failure: How is access to mysql configured? Has the user access when connecting from 127.0.0.1? When glassfish connects to the local ssh tunnel endpoint, for the mysql server it looks as somebody from it's mysql-server-localhost is connecting.

Can you login into the server that glassfish is running on and do a

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 13306 -u user -p
```

from there. If this is not working you check the access configuration for users accessing from localhost and 127.0.0.1

the third reason might be a missing installation of the mysql connector library in Glassfish. This is [described in the mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html), basically:

> Once GlassFish is installed, make sure it can access MySQL Connector/J. To do this, copy the MySQL Connector/J jar file to the domain-dir/lib directory. For example, copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar to C:\glassfish-install-path\domains\domain-name\lib. Restart the GlassFish Application Server. For more information, see “Integrating the JDBC Driver” in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Administration Guide, available at GlassFish Server Documentation.

**Update**

added the *:mysql:* part in the connection url and reference to connector installation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I afraid make you confuse.

My problem are the remote JDBC url does not work.

I can connect MySQL server from the glasfish host
`mysql -h remote -u user -p`
Also via ssh tunnel
`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 13306 -u user -p`

Comment: forgot mysql spec in the url, check the updated answer

Comment: I had installed a MySQL JDBC driver, and other databases on the local host are working.

Comment: Can you please show the jdbc connection URL you are using?

Comment: I am using several databases.
`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:13306/portal`
`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:23306/Star`
`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/enq`
and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again, the problem no longer reproduced.

I am not sure if my configuration somewhere wrong.